# Do Not Disturb mode - always silent incoming calls

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I have an app with an integrated music player. I don't want the music to be interrupted by incoming calls.

I use following function for that:

```
public static void updateDoNotDisturbMode(boolean enabled, boolean checkPrefs)
{
    ...
    AudioManager audioManager = ((AudioManager) MainApp.get().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE));
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) MainApp.get().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    if (!enabled)
    {
        audioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);

        ...
    }
    else
    {
        audioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);

        ...
    }
}
```

**what works**

- silent phone if no headphones are connected
- internal music player does play on without interruption if someone calls
- so without headphones connected, everything works perfectly fine

**what does not work**

- if headphones are connected, the standard beep sound is interrupting my music player and is played in the headphones

*How can I avoid that incoming calls are interrupting my music player even if headphones are connected?*

**TARGET SDK**

Only 4.2 and upwarts... (including 5)

Comment: set silent profile pro-grammatically when your apps starts and when close then enable it to general, it works even if earphone is connected.

Comment: tried that with using the vibration only profile... with this, it does definitely not work... Btw. I really would like to use the vibration only profile at most... I will try that again if I don't find any solution... But I think, I'm not 100% sure, even the silent profile does not solve the headphone problem...

Comment: but i am sure, once i did the same, right now i don't have sources, if i get sources then i,ll give you a work around even!

Comment: thanks. I will try it in the evening and check your suggestion. Anyways, setting the profile to silent by hand should be enough to test it I think... But I'll try it

Comment: play music in your device and set your profile to silent, connect headphones, and make a call on your device form other device, your phone will not ring not even your music stops.

Comment: I tested that now... my integrated music player is interrupted and the peep sound is played. I even testet the original music player. This one gets silent if the phone is muted, with and without headphones... no peep and no music is played there...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean integrated music player? Can you change code of music app?

A player stops playing because it listens to PhoneStateChanges - `void onCallEvent(int state, String number);`
If you can change code of the player you should check is mute mode on within this method - if yes then do not stop playback.

If you can't change the code of player - you can use advanced player with preferences of audio focus. For example poweramp has such option. Set Settings/Audio/Audio Focus/Pause in Call to false (it works, tested right now). But you should change it manually all the time.

Comment: I use a audio focus based system. Of course, I can ignore that and play on with my music, but this won't stop the beep from the call to interrupt my music player... Interrupting won't stop my player, if I solve it this way, but still the beep sound will overlay my players music...

Comment: @prom85 have you bluetooth headphones or wired?

Comment: bluetooth... but I think I tested it with wired ones as well... but I'm not sure now

Comment: @prom85 
I tested it right now with wired headphones and nexus 5 device, and i didn't get any interruption or beep. Try it with wired.

Comment: I will try it. Btw, I am sure the problem does not exist on all phones. I know, the same technic worked on my old HTC One Mini 2 but does not work on my new Samsung Alpha now... Still I will check that and I will test, if poweramp does work on my phone as expected

Comment: I tried it now. The poweramp player does not stop music if I deactivate the setting for this behaviour... but a call is played in the headphones AND on the phone... and is overlaying the music from poweramp

Comment: @prom85 just disable sound of call. It can be done either manually or programatically.

Comment: what do you mean? change the phones sound profile to silent? Actually, this does not change my originally described problem... This will lead to a silent call, if no headphones are connected and my music player works perfectly fine, but still the beep sound is played in the headphones, even with the silent profile selected... so no improvement to my above posted solution... which does not change any profile...